# "Inconclusive: Test not run" error running unit tests in debug mode in Visual Studio / Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, resharper

I am getting the above error "**Inconclusive: Test not run**" error when trying to run my unit tests in debug mode in Visual Studio.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 patched with the latest .NET Core 2 release Version 15.3.5 and Resharper Ultimate 2017.1.3

This has only started happening since I installed the latest .NET Core 2.0 patch recently.

Comment: For me, this was happening because I left my soln in Release mode after profiling. The Release build configuration was set to ignore my unit test project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This bug](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465541) has been fixed in [R# 2017.2 release build](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/)

Comment: Let me download and install it and see what happens. Thanks.

Comment: That worked. I'll mark this as the answer. Many thanks :)

Comment: Looks like not. I have Resharper 2017.2.1 and VS 2015 v.14.0.25422.01 update 3. 
And nunit 3.6.1  
Sometime after edit I runt single test in debug mode and it wails. Re-run of test helps.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Upgraded Resharper to 2017.2.2 in VS 2017 version 15.3.4, and now debug of unit tests is not returning inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible answer is to prevent VS from using test settings file. Located in "Test->Test Settings" menu. After changing branches it got enabled somehow without me noticing and tests stopped running. Unchecking it brought my tests back to runnable state.
[Test settings file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9oKfI.png)